# How to make a JFrame fit the full screen?

Tags: java, jframe

So, I was creating a JFrame object. It has a method to set the size of the frame.

What would be the parameters of that method to make the frame span my entire screen?

Answer (score 2):

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()
```